# Excel VBA: if value in row(x) = value in row (x+1) in column C then sort values in column H

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm very new to Excel VBA.

Every month I import a spreadsheet of multiple customers' data that is already separated by customer in column C (account number).  Within each account number, I need to then sort the rows into alphanumeric order based on column E (service).

In other words, I need a macro that will sort the values in column E **only if** the values in column C are equal to each other.

Macro must also skip any irrelevant rows, some of which contain merged cells.

FYI - the format of all the values = text, other than column I (charge amount).

Any help greatly appreciated - apologies ahead of time if I haven't made my question clear enough!

Below is a spreadsheet example:
[image: sort service within each account number]

Comment: Use `With ... End With` combined with `.CurrentRegion`, `.Resize` and `.End(xlDown)` to cycle through the grouped data, sorting each group as you progress through.

Comment: SO is not a code writing website. What have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Developer tab and click "Record Macro". Give the macro any name (Excel's suggestion is fine).

Perform the actions to sort the data, such as selct the data, swt the Sort settings etc.

Click "Stop recording" in teh developer tab.

Goto to VB and open the macro you just recorded. Use the code as a basis for your actual macro. You can record anything you want to know in additional recorded macros. The rest I leave to you. Come back when you have problems with your code.